# Смена оборудования, смена настроек, зеркалирование трафика провайдеру. Разбор своих косяков и старого админа

Tags: сеть, cisco

Имеющееся оборудование:

```
Eltex LTP-8x выданный IP для примера 192.168.1.2  
Cisco 7301 : ip 192.168.1.1  
Catalyst 9600 Cisco : ip 192.168.1.3 | идёт замена на SNR-s2985G-24T
```

Как всё подключено постарался изобразить на картинке.

Так как по сути новичок в этом деле, до этого только занимался малыми сетями, хочется услышать как всё сделать ПРАВИЛЬНО.

А требуется вот что. перенести подключение(входящее от провайдера) с ELTEX в SNR-s2985G-24T а потом грамотно всё развести маршрутизатор | ELTEX => абоненты
последнее сейчас работает и всё более чем устраивает, на каждого абонента выделен один VLAN с диапазоном адресов DHCP сервером служит ELTEX.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: то что хотелось бы получить на выходе]

Comment: Составьте полную схему сети, которую Вы хотите получить. Тогда будет предмет для разговора. А что-то мыслить, не имея ни ТЗ, ни реализующего это ТЗ проекта, на одних хотелках, как минимум неразумно.

Comment: @Akina добавил изображение. По сути нужно заменить Catalyst 9600 Cisco  на SNR-s2985G-24T вот как и стоит сейчас и перекинуть входящее подключение c ELTEX в новый SNR так как у Catalist не sfp не оптики ( а оставлять так не выйдет, т.к. Eltex попросту не пропускает зеркалированный трафик, по крайней мере так сказал другой админ. )

Comment: Ну вообще-то приходящий Инет должен подключаться к WAN-порту NAT-маршрутизатора (кто это в Вашей схеме?), а его LAN-порт и ваши локальные серверы/клиенты - в коммутатор. Так, чисто теоретически...

Comment: @Akina Мне сию схему, то что снизу на чёрном фоне накидал админ провайдера от которого идёт поставка инэта, причём было это вообще сделана карандашом и скорее всего на коленке. Сам я не силён в работе с железом данного вида. Хотя и так понял что он от меня хотел (вплане подключение). Просто занимался до этого только хабы да комп с двумя сетевухами и сборкой линукса для инэта на 20 - 30 компов. А тут такие заморочки вышли и зеркало предоставить надо. А то что стоит сейчас Catalyst 9600 Cisco не имеет SFP порта и входящий не сделать, вот и по совету того админа и началось всё.